# Usign resolution show that the statement $\neg P \rightarrow (\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P)$ is true

Tags: logic

> Show using resolution that the statement $\neg P \rightarrow (\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P)$  holds.

I've found out that this statement is actually a tautology and it seems to be true that the cnf of a tautology is $1$. I am not familiar with the resolution technique so any hints on what is supposed to do here would be very helpful.

Comment: Transform it in *clause* form: $P \lor Q \lor \lnot P$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use resolution to show that a statement is a tautology: you need to first negate the statement, and then put it in CNF.  From the clauses you get from that, you should be able to resolve an empty clause (=contradiction).  So, given that a contradiction can be inferred from the negation of the statement, the statement itself must be a tautology. And, of course, if the statement is a tautology, then it is also just plain true.

So in this case, you get:

Negate statement:

$\neg(\neg P \rightarrow (\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P))$

Put into CNF:

$\neg(\neg P \rightarrow (\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P)) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land \neg (\neg Q\rightarrow \neg P) \Leftrightarrow \neg P \land Q\land P$

Clause set:

$\{ \{ \neg P \}, \{ Q \}, \{ P \} \}$

Resolve:

Resolve $\{ \neg P \}$ and $\{ P \}$ to get $\{ \}$